# Work for/work in

Tags: prepositions

Let's say you are on an interview, and you are explaining the reason why you have chosen the country you wanted to work **for**

> I really wanted to live and work in that country, that's why I am doing my best, besides, this is the country I chose to work **for**

Or

> I really wanted to live and work in that country, that's why I am doing my best, besides, this is the country I chose to work **in**

Usually, we use **work+on** in the middle of a sentence right? But when the **work+preposition** is at the end, it gets me a bit confused. Which is corrrect?

Comment: work for a company, work in a city, work on a project. You only work "for" a country, if you are in the military or high-level government office. This is the country I chose to work in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really wanted to live and work in **this** country [speaking to interviewer], that's why I am doing my best, besides, this is the country I chose to work in.

That's fine in speech. You can leave the preposition at the end, it's acceptable in speech.

This is the country I chose to work in = This is the country  in which I chose to work.

In speaking, we leave prepositions at the end of sentences.

Comment: So you mean, it is unacceptable if you leave a preposition at the end of a sentence in writing? Just to confirm...

Comment: Not necessarily. But in formal writing, one tries to avoid it if possible. There are times when it is unavoidable.